# Facebook Account Kit UI Customization

Tags: android, account-kit

While using facebook account kit I found that its listing all the county codes but I just want to target this app only for particular country.
And I also know that we can use `setDefaultCountryCode(String defaultCountryCode)` in `AccountKitConfigurationBuilder` to give default value.

I have already searched for solutions which would disable the click on country code spinner in default theme provided by facebook but I didn't find any solution.

So while reading facebook account kit [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/accountkitconfigurationbuilder) I found that we can have a list of country codes which can be passed to `setSMSWhitelist(String[] smsWhitelist)` method of `AccountKitConfigurationBuilder`, this will show the list of country codes which we want to target.

```
    String[] smsWhitelist = new String[]{"IN"};
    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, AccountKitActivity.class);
    AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =
            new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
                    LoginType.PHONE,
                    AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN); 
    configurationBuilder.setReadPhoneStateEnabled(true);
    configurationBuilder.setSMSWhitelist(smsWhitelist);
    configurationBuilder.setUIManager(uiManager);
    configurationBuilder.setReceiveSMS(true);
```

So this solved by requirement but I got some UI design flaw while showing list of particular country codes, something `round corner transparent overlay dialog` is appearing in background of popup spinner dialog like this

[image]

which also seems to appear while showing all country codes (see bottom)

[image]

Can this be solved? Or am I missing something while styling the theme

`uiManager = new ThemeUIManager(R.style.LoginTheme);`

```
   <style name="LoginTheme" parent="Theme.AccountKit">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_disabled_background_color">#9ebcff</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_primary_color">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_primary_text_color">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_secondary_text_color">#2c2e70</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_background_color">#2c2e70</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_border_color">#2c2e70</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_title_text_color">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_background_color">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_input_accent_color">#ffffff</item>


    <item name="com_accountkit_input_background_color">#2c2e70</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_input_text_color">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="com_accountkit_button_text_color">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I was randomly looking for customizing Account Kit, when I saw your question. This gave me a clue and I also found a solution to your problem. This is the sample app for Android with some sample implementation for Advanced UI: [Account Kit Samples for Android, Facebook](https://github.com/fbsamples/account-kit-samples-for-android/tree/master/samples/AccountKitSample/src/main/java/com/example/accountkitsample) It has some code related to changing the Spinner theme, I hope it helps. :)